# How to Use Correlation Against the Output in Spark using Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, matrix

I'm working through the O'Reilly book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and in the end-to-end Machine Learning example, where we work with a housing data set, I came across the section where we use some statistics like toe Corelation to determine how dependent the Input features are to the output and in Python with the Pandas library, it is as simple as doing this:

```
corr_matrix = housing.corr()
```

It then does the following:

```
corr_matrix["median_house_value].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Which then gives a nice textual output of the corelation of the median_house_value to all the other input features. I now kind of tried to replicate this using Spark in Scala and I have the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Matrix
 
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("longitude", "latitude", "housing_median_age", "total_rooms", "population", "households", "median_income", "median_house_value"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
 
val assembled = assembler.transform(dfRaw)

val coeff_df = Correlation.corr(assembled, "features")

val Row(coeff_matrix: Matrix) = coeff_df.head
println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n " + coeff_matrix.toString(10, 100000))
```

As it can be seen that I can print the Matrix, but how could I replicate that one line of Python code in Scala so that I get to see a similiar result in ascending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do it, so I came up with this that pretty much does what I want:

```
coeff_matrix.rowIter.toSeq.last.toDense.toArray.sorted.reverse foreach println
```

Gives me:

```
1.0
0.6880752079585478
0.13415311380656308
0.10562341249320993
0.06584265057005646
-0.024649678888894886
-0.04596661511797852
-0.14416027687465932
```

The result is not so intuitive as it was with the Python version. But at least I was able to bring it close enough.